# Recieve Jquery Ajax data using Python Cgi Script on apache2 webserver

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, apache, cgi

So I have attempted to implement this:

This html page on my website has a script which based on key presses, sends data to a cgi script on a Raspberry Pi:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/aj..."></script>

<script>
var map = {};
$(document).keydown(function(e){
e = e || event;
map[e.keyCode] = true;
}).keyup(function(e){
if (map[38] && map[40]) {
$.ajax({
url: "http://ip-address/cgi-bin/data.py",
data: {q: 'Brake' }
});
}
else if (map[37] && map[39]) {
$.ajax({
url: "http://ip-address/cgi-bin/data.py",
data: {q: 'Brake' }
});
}
else if (map[38] && map[37]){
$.ajax({
url: "http://ip-address/cgi-bin/data.py",
data: {q: 'UpLeft' }
});
}
else if (map[38] && map[39]){
$.ajax({
url: "http://ip-address/cgi-bin/data.py",
data: {q: 'UpRight' }
});
}
else if (map[40] && map[37]){
$.ajax({
url: "http://ip-address/cgi-bin/data.py",
data: {q: 'DownLeft' }
});
}
else if (map[40] && map[39]){
$.ajax({
url: "http://ip-address/cgi-bin/data.py",
data: {q: 'DownRight' }
});
}
else if (map[38]){
$.ajax({
url: "http://ip-address/cgi-bin/data.py",
data: {q: 'Up' }
});
}
else if (map[40]) {
$.ajax({
url: "http://ip-address/cgi-bin/data.py",
data: {q: 'Down' }
});
}
else if (map[37]) {
$.ajax({
url: "http://ip-address/cgi-bin/data.py",
data: {q: 'Left' }
});
}
else if (map[39]) {
$.ajax({
url: "http://ip-address/cgi-bin/data.py",
data: {q: 'Right' }
});
}
map[e.keyCode] = false;
});
</script>
```

Now for receiving the data and sending it to an arduino, I have followed the directions at http://www.civrays.com/myrobot/news/pythoncgi.

To test this, I am using my ubuntu laptop before programming it into the pi.

I setup the apache2 webserver on my ubuntu system successfully. I then placed "data.py" into /usr/lib/cgi-bin (configuring Apache2 with Python CGI). The contents of the python file are as follows:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import cgi
import serial

def arduino(cmd):  
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0') #USB
    ser.write(cmd + "\n")
    ser.close

data = cgi.FieldStorage()
if "q" in data:
    q = data["q"].value
    print "The data is: " + q
    arduino(q)
```

I made sure to execute "sudo chmod 777 /usr/lib/cgi-bin/data.py"

(Regarding sending data through the serial port, I did overwrite the permissions by adding the apache2 server to the dialout group, but right now I just want to have this cgi script receive the ajax data, then I will worry about the arduino portion.)

However, nothing gets printed, so I don't believe I am receiving my data. However, as CGI scripts execute when called, I'm not even sure how to check if I'm receiving data. What could possibly be the issue? How can I debug this?

Comment: I don't understand the infinite loop at the end. CGI doesn't work like that; a script is only called once in response to an http request.

Comment: And you don't run CGI scripts from the command line, either; again, the web server calls them in response to a request.

Comment: Ah, I'll make the corresponding edits. If this is true, then how can I check that I'm receiving the data sent from the webpage?